# Active Effects only half powerful

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've been messing around a while, and randomly stumbled upon some "errors" in my "Active Effects" page. The items I have, and even the Agent of Mara buff provided through the Riften Temple's questline are only half as powerful as they should be.

Initially thinking this was a simple display order, I tested it out. I have carry weight on my gloves for instance, and it indeed only removed half the value stated on the item from unequipping, again only adding half when equipping once more.

I've tried through the console removing my "Atronach" and "Magic Resistance" perks from the alteration tree, without any effect. Switching my current active standing stone away from the Atronach stone does not seem to solve this either (even though the 50% exact made me think this might be the case).

A quick list of mods I have installed (in load order):

- Dawnguard
- Hearthfire
- Dragonborn
- Unofficial Patch
- High-Res packs (official)
- Unofficial High-Res Packs Patch
- Hearthfire Display Case Fix
- SkyUI
- SimplyKnock
- Immersive Armors
- Immersive Weapons
- Immersive Music
- Ordinator's Perk Overhaul
- Organised Bandits of Skyrim
- Immersive Patrols
- Campfire
- Frostfall
- Hunterborn
- Alternate Start - Live Another Life

Comment: If you turn all the mods off, does it still happen?

Comment: There is like 400 perks in Ordinator's Perk Overhaul, I can Imagine something in that mod causes the problem

Comment: Turning off all the mods doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Is this OG Skyrim or SSE?

Comment: Original version

Comment: So after doublechecking I've found something unusual. Though the Agent of Mara still only gives 7% Magic Resistance (which should be 15%), the potion created by Esbern does still give me 25% damage reduction versus Dragons in melee combat. On top of this, the Wood Elf racial also still grants 50% poison and disease resistance. Everything else is halved except for those two.

Comment: Well that is certainly odd. If turning the mods off doesn't fix it, then there's probably something wrong with your save, possible caused by one of the mods. If you have any saves from before this started happening, I'd load one of those. If not, you could check if it is limited to that character by making a new one.

Comment: Probably it is something in the save file caused by the mods. Made a new character, with all the mods and added the agent of mara through the console. It grants 15% rather than 7% on this character. I'll see about adding everything step by step the same as my other character and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two other options that come to mind:

[**Thoroughly checking the mods for conflicts**](https://wiki.step-project.com/Basics_of_Resolving_Conflicts) **using** [**TES5Edit**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25859) will be considerably time-consuming, but is still an option (provided your problem is caused by conflicting mods, and not, as mentioned, by your save file).

However, I once had a problem with an invisibility effect (I think that of the Shadowcloak of Nocturnal - it would wear off almost immediately after sneaking) and was able to **resolve it by using a batch file that removed ALL active spells and effects**.
You can find this batch file under *Solution 4* on [this page](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/872861-tutorial-removing-unwanted-magic-effects-from-the-player/) (and [here](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=40779) is a direct link. It was created by NexusForums user *LubitelSofta*. You need a free account in order to download).
Be sure to take off all your (enchanted) gear beforehand.

Additionally, you might want to try **cleaning your saved game**, using either [Skyrim Save Cleaner](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31724), [FallrimTools ReSaver](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/5031/), or the [Save game script cleaner](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52363/).
Download and install any one of them, and follow the steps mentioned on their respective Nexus page.

Answer (score 0):

So I've had this bug too and it would return like all PERKEFFECTS after I resurrect myself and reload.
FIXED IT TODAY REMOVING THE ATRONACH PERK THAT IS NOT THE ONE MENTIONED IN ALTERATIONSCHOOL. Open console and type `help "atronach"` and search for the 2 listed as `"PERK" 00058something` is the one you keep. Remove the other with command `"player.removeperk <ID>"`